# Using rvalues with the & operator

Tags: c, literals, rvalue, lvalue

I've been struggling to understand the C code below:

```
struct s {
        char m1;
        char m2;
};

int  main()
{
    /* This will print 1 */
    printf("%d\n", &((struct s*)0)->m2);

}
```

The portion below seems to behave a bit confusing under slight modification:

```
&((struct s*)0)->m2
```

On compiling, and running the initial code,I get an answer of 1, which I expect to get.

I modify the code by replacing `&((struct s*)0)->m2` with
`&((struct s*)0)`, and then I get an error saying that, "lvalue required as unary '&' operand".

**QUESTION**: In the original code portion, `&((struct s*)0)->m2`, wasn't the argument to `&` an rvalue? If so, why did it reach compilation success then but not in the case of the modification `&((struct s*)0)`?

Answer (score 2):

In this case:

```
 &((struct s*)0)
```

The operand to `&` is the result of a cast which is always an rvalue.  While in this case:

```
&((struct s*)0)->m2
```

The operand to `&` is the result of the `->` operator which is an lvalue, specifically the named field.  Also note that this expression results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because a NULL pointer value is being dereferenced via the `->` operator.